# Multiple criteria lookup in categorical data

Tags: excel, categorical-data

I've got some raw data like the one shown below and I want to search the value under, **Category** **B**, **sub-category** **3**. This is something like a pivot table in compact display form.

I cannot simply use MATCH function since the name of the category is not displayed on each row. I reckon I could probably use an extra lookup column and add some mappings but that seems rather fiddly.

```
Category   Sub-Category  Value
   A         1             431
             2             543
             3           13421
             4             754
             5              43

   B         1             456
             2              35
             3             906

   C         1             562
             2              13
             3            1243
             4             765
             5              35
             6              12
```

Comment: See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le). As purely supplemental information, you can post an image to any public file share ([imgur.com](http://imgur.com/) is a nice one) and edit your question to include the public link. Very often someone with a little more rep will come along and edit your question to include the image from the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pairs to reshape the ranges searched through with the lookups.

[image: INDEX / MATCH function pairs]

The standard formula in G2 is,

```
=INDEX(INDEX(C$2:C$999, MATCH(E2, A$2:A$999, 0)):C$999, MATCH(F2, INDEX(B$2:B$999, MATCH(E2, A$2:A$999, 0)):B$999, 0))
```

Fill down as necessary.

Comment: Impressive! Thank you @Jeeped, I didn't even know the INDEX function can return the cell reference!